# Can't reproduce openssl command with BouncyCastle

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, sign

I am trying, for already a couple of weeks to reproduce some openssl commands using bouncycastle and java.

After following a lot of samples and trying a lot of examples from Stackoverflow, I still can't make it work, thats why I'm asking for help now.

The openssl commands I have to reproduce are :

```
openssl smime -sign -in fileToSign.eml -out signedFile.step2 -passin pass:« password» -binary -nodetach -signer myprivatecert.pem -certfile mypubliccert.pem
```

This first commands takes 3 files, the file to sign, a private certificate and a public certificate.

It returns a file looking like :

> MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename="smime.p7m" Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime;
>   smime-type=signed-data; name="smime.p7m" Content-Transfer-Encoding:
>   base64
>
> MIJAYAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIJAUTCCQE0CAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADCCNTUG
>   CSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCNSYEgjUiQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiBtdWx0aXBhcnQvbWl4ZWQ7
>   CmJvdW5kYXJ5PSItLS0tPUxPR0lQT0xfTUlGXzE1NDY4NTAwNDc4MTYiCi0tLS0t
>   LT1MT0dJUE9MX01JRl8xNTQ2ODUwMDQ3ODE2DQpDb250ZW50LVR5cGU6IHRleHQv
>   WE1MOw0KbmFtZT0iUERBX1A5MDAxMjZfMDA1XzIwMTkwMTA3LjA5MzIwMF8wMDAw
>   MV9JTklULnhtbCI7IGZpbGVuYW1lPSJQREFfUDkwMDEyNl8wMDVfMjAxOTAxMDcu
>   MDkzMjAwXzAwMDAxX0lOSVQueG1sIg0KQ29udGVudC1UcmFuc2Zlci1FbmNvZGlu
>   ZzogYmFzZTY0DQoNClBEOTRiV3dnZG1WeWMybHZiajBpTVM0d0lpQmxibU52Wkds
>   dVp6MGlWVlJHTFRnaVB6NDhUVWxHVmtGUFNXNW1iMGx1YVhScFlXeGwNClBnbzhT
>   VzVtYjNNK0NqeFdaWEp6YVc5dVBqSXVPVHd2Vm1WeWMybHZiajRLUEVodmNtOWtZ
>   WFJsUGpJd01Ua3RNREV0TURkVU1EazYNCk16UTZNRGM4TDBodmNtOWtZWFJsUGdv
>   OFUyRnBjMmxsU0c5eWIyUmhkR1UrTWpBeE9TMHdNUzB3TjFRd09Ub3pNam93TUR3...

Second command I have to use is :

```
openssl smime -encrypt -in signedFile.step2 -out encryptedFile.P7M -outform DER -binary anotherpubliccertificate.pub.pem
```

This command takes 2 files, the file signed by the previous command and a public certificate, different than the one used in the previous command.

This returns a binary file, an encrypted file generated from step 2.

Any of the examples I found over the internet helped me to get a file looking like these previous ones, not even close.

I hope someone can help

**Edit**
A few examples of what I tried, or refered to, until now

[sign file with bouncy castle in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175475/sign-file-with-bouncy-castle-in-java) -> This returned a signed file that do not correspond to the signed file generated with openssl

[AES encrypt/decrypt with Bouncy Castle provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925029/aes-encrypt-decrypt-with-bouncy-castle-provider) -> Again, this isn't working, the result doesn't correspond to the encrypted file I generate with openssl

https://studylibfr.com/doc/3898805/cryptographie-avec-bouncy-castle---zenk -> Have been following the whole tutorial, not getting the expected result

[X509 RSA bouncy castle sign and verify plain text in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877488/x509-rsa-bouncy-castle-sign-and-verify-plain-text-in-java) -> Signed file not corresponding too

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples/CreateSignedMultipartMail.java -> This class generate something that looks alike to what I'm trying to get, but I couldn't test it's validity as I have to encrypt it and still can't make encrytion work

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples/ReadSignedMail.java -> Same as previous class

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples/SendSignedAndEncryptedMail.java -> This method of encryption isn't returning the same result as openssl, so it isn't working

For sure, I've tried to keep working on these samples classes from bouncycastle, but without success.

Any help would be appreciated

**Edit 2**
The answer of the following question [Sign and encrypt a file using S/MIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257451/sign-and-encrypt-a-file-using-s-mime) returns a Base64 encoded file that might correspond to what I generate with openssl. But the problem is that my entry file is about 25kb and the signed file generated is only 3kb, I don't understand why, I noticed that at this line :

```
CMSTypedData content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(buffer);
CMSSignedData signedData = signGen.generate(content, false);
byte[] signeddata = signedData.getEncoded();
```

the getEncoded() method returns me a byte array much smaller than the buffer I send to the CMSSignedData.

Does anyone knows the reason ?

Comment: Interpreting a binary format as text is foolish; lookup what DER means.

Comment: I know what DER means, thanks, this doesn't help me to understand how to get a file looking alike. I wrote these characters as an example of what it looks like

Comment: I guess this is why mankind invented hexadecimals. If you understand DER then you don't post UTF-8 decoding of it. Mr zero sequence. For these kind of questions you are supposed to post the code you've developed so far.

Comment: As said on my question above, I tried a lot of samples, literally so much, I can't post just everything I have done since everything I tried didn't return the result I have to get. I'm asking this question expecting that someone would get a way to get this result, not to show everything I've tried and failed, but I will edit my question and add a few examples of what I've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the signing, you were fairly close with `org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.examples.CreateSignedMultipartMail` except that

- it does multipart *data*, which `openssl smime` doesn't do; start from `CreateSignedMail` instead
- it does multipart *signing*, aka clear-signing, which `openssl smime` also defaults to, but `-nodetach` changes this to embedded aka encapsulated
- it includes a full cert chain, but a self-generated one of length only 2 whereas nearly all 'real' certs are longer, whereas openssl by default includes only the signer cert
- by default it uses some signedattributes different than openssl

For the encryption (or more exactly enveloping) `openssl smime -outform der` in spite of the name doesn't do SMIME at all, it does CMS (originally and still also known as PKCS7). Bouncy uses the full OO goodness of Java to put CMS and SMIME, which are very similar but not the same, into different classes that are related but not the same, so you need the CMS class(es).

Putting these together (plus a minimal test harness) I present to you:

```
    // for test, (own) signing key+certchain and (peer) encryption cert in file
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); ks.load(new FileInputStream(args[0]),args[1].toCharArray());
    PrivateKey signkey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(args[2], args[1].toCharArray());
    Certificate[] signcert = ks.getCertificateChain(args[2]);
    Certificate encrcert = ks.getCertificate(args[3]);
    // and data in file
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(new File(args[4]).toPath());

    // adapted from org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.examples.CreateSignedMail 
    // OpenSSL uses this rather silly capability list; may not be needed 
    SMIMECapabilityVector       caps = new SMIMECapabilityVector();
    caps.addCapability(SMIMECapability.aES256_CBC);
    caps.addCapability(SMIMECapability.aES192_CBC);
    caps.addCapability(SMIMECapability.aES128_CBC);
    caps.addCapability(SMIMECapability.dES_EDE3_CBC);
    caps.addCapability(SMIMECapability.rC2_CBC, 128);
    caps.addCapability(SMIMECapability.rC2_CBC, 64);
    caps.addCapability(SMIMECapability.dES_CBC);
    caps.addCapability(SMIMECapability.rC2_CBC, 40);
    ASN1EncodableVector signedAttrs = new ASN1EncodableVector();
    signedAttrs.add(new SMIMECapabilitiesAttribute(caps));
    // Bouncy default adds RFC6211 in addition to standard ctype, stime, mdgst
    // and changing this is complicated; recipient _should_ ignore unneeded attr

    SMIMESignedGenerator gen = new SMIMESignedGenerator();
    gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder()//.setProvider("BC") not needed
        .setSignedAttributeGenerator(new AttributeTable(signedAttrs))
        .build("SHA1withRSA", signkey, (X509Certificate) signcert[0]) ); 
    // change sigalg if key not RSA and/or want better hash
    // OpenSSL by default includes only signer cert; recipient may want more
    gen.addCertificates(new JcaCertStore (Arrays.asList (new Certificate[]{signcert[0]}) ));

    MimeBodyPart msg = new MimeBodyPart();
    msg.setText(new String(data, "ISO-8859-1")); // OpenSSL doesn't know charsets
    ByteArrayOutputStream temp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    gen.generateEncapsulated(msg).writeTo(temp); // OpenSSL -nodetach is encapsulated
    // Bouncy uses BER here (unlike OpenSSL DER) 
    // and I don't see a simple way to change it but it _should_ not matter 
    byte[] signedblob = temp.toByteArray();

    // now CMS (not SMIME) enveloping
    CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator edgen = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();
    edgen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator((X509Certificate) encrcert));
    CMSEnvelopedData edmsg = edgen.generate( new CMSProcessableByteArray(signedblob),
            new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.DES_EDE3_CBC).build() );
    byte[] encrblob = edmsg.toASN1Structure().getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DER); // OpenSSL is DER though std doesn't require it

    // for test, write to a file
    Files.write(new File(args[5]).toPath(), encrblob);
```

On, and 'does anyone know the reason'

```
CMSSignedData signedData = signGen.generate(content, false);
byte[] signeddata = signedData.getEncoded();
```

is smaller than the content? See [the javadoc](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.html#generate-org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedData-boolean-) -- with `encapsulate` (the second parameter) set to `false` you told it to *not* include the content in the signature (more exactly SignedData), and it did as you demanded.

Comment: Hello,
Sorry for my late answer, it seems that, thanks to your answer, the problem of encryption is now solved ! Thank you so much for this, you saved my life
Now for the signature, I couldn't try it yet, but I noticed that the header of the smime file is quite different than the one generated by openssl, for sure this might not be important, but here is what I noticed : 
- Content type attribute with OpenSSL is : application/x-pkcs7-mime and with BouncyCastle : application/pkcs7-mime
I wish you can help me to solve this, thank you again so much for your help